# How to make a normal post request in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

My question is very simple... I need to make a regular post request in angular 4 app, like as html form post, that is that replace the window location..because if I do it using HttpClient, this makes an ajax POST...
My question is... How to make a non ajax post request in angular 4?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even need "normal" POST request? Angular 4 is designed for single page applications which do not require page reloading. That's why all requests are  async (via ajax).

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, if you want to post a form in the traditional fashion use a traditional form. If you want to navigate somewhere use an `<a href` link. If you absolutely want to navigate somewhere with javascript use `navigator.location.href = "url"`

Comment: I need to integrate an external service ... to be precise a webcheckout ... I need to redirect the flow of my application to that external provider to make the payments and then return to my angular application

Comment: idk exactly what you need but sounds like you are talking about http request. there's http request and httpClent. Try http request..but the cool kidz use httpClient. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

How about using `HttpClient` and **setting or reloading location on success**?

Here is an example how to do it:

```
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('name', 'Max Mustermann');

this.http.post('http://myapiserver.com', formdata).subscribe(
    res => {
        // reloading location
        location.reload();

        // or navigate with:
        // this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
        // or with
        // this._router.navigate(['Home']);
    }
);
```